# Can't find Excel partial strikethrough text (.NET)

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, interop, excel-interop

Help me please find all partial strikethrough cells in an excel file.

[image]

I can find easily all the strikethrough/non strikethrough cells just using two lines of code:

```
Application.FindFormat.Font.Strikethrough = True
Dim cell = range.Cells.Find("", SearchFormat:=True)
```

This code will give me the first cell that has the property `Strikethrough` set to `True`. The same with `False`. Using a loop, I'm finding very fast the full strikethrough cells.
The problem here is that if there is a cell that has two words, and one word is Strikethrough, then this cell has the `Font.Strikethrough` property equal to `DBNull.Value` or `{}`.

If I try to use the same code but to put instead of `True` -> `Application.FindFormat.Font.Strikethrough = DBNull.Value`, are returned all the non-strikethrough cells, what's equivalent to `cell.Font.Strikethrough = False`.

I've read all the possible articles, and everywhere I find only one solution, to iterate through each cell and to check if at least one char of its text is `char.Font.Strikethrough = True`. This is the worst solution, because I have an example of 30.000 cells, and only one cell has partial strikethrough text.

Using `Range.Find` method, I'm finding very fast all the strikethrough cells.
Converting this range to array, or list where we can use conditions to find, or even to iterate through range to check if `IsDbNull(cell.Font.Strikethrough)` are the wors solutions, and for 30.000 cells is taking about 20 minutes to find the partial strikethrough cells.

One more thing, I haven't found on internet even how we can find the partial strikethrough cells using Excel only. So, the Excel has the solution to find the strikethrough just putting the format that you want - `True` or `False` to the strikethrough, but for partial -> Nothing.
[image]

An ideal solution would be something similar to:

```
Application.FindFormat.Font.Strikethrough = DBNull.Value
Dim cell = range.Cells.Find("", SearchFormat:=True)
```

(but, as I said earlier, this is interpretated as `Strikethrough = False`)

Sorry for the long post.

PS: Using `VB.Net`, `Interop.Excel.Range`.

Comment: Partial formatting is done on the character level.  So If strikethrough is negative for the entire cell, you will need to examine each character. (Obviously, you don't have to do that if the cell is positive for strikthough).  You can't do that with Range.Find.  You will have to loop through the entire search range (or at least the range for which strikethrough = false) and then each character in the cell.

Comment: If you want to find both whole and partial strikethroughs, you can also check the characters as a single character will also return true if the entire cell as been set to that format.

Comment: Ron, thanks for the answer, but if the cell has partial strikethrough, the property "cell.Format.Strikethrough" Will not be True, and will not be False. It will be equal to DBNull.Value, equivalent to "{}", this means mixed format. So we know which of them are partial. So I will iterate through chars only for those, not through all that have False. But what about your second comment? I think I did not understand correctly...

Comment: I just don't want to jump through all 30k to read the strikethrough property to have the value "{}" to do something with it...because it takes 20 minutes to do that...

Comment: Are there faster ways to find them?

Comment: I don't know any faster way, at least not in Excel. And yes, if you are looking for all strikethroughs, whether partial or full, and most (or a lot) of them are full, you can just search the `non-full` cells.  Unfortunate that Application.FindFormat cannot differentiate between null and false.  Can C# do that?

Comment: Yes, C# can... But you need to call the cell first to find out that the result is not True or False but "{}"